# How to test a prop of a prop of a nested component with Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a prop of a React component that lives as a prop of another component. The whole stuff looks like this:

```
export default ({ propToTest }) => (
  <MainComponent>
    <SubComponent prop1={<SubSubComponent propToTest={propToTest} />} />
  </MainComponent>
);
```

I want to test with Enzyme the prop `propToTest` of the component `SubSubComponent`. For that I wrote the following script:

```
describe('MainComponent test', () => {
  it('takes propToTest correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MainComponent />);
    const subsubComponent = wrapper
      .find('SubComponent')
      .dive()
      .find('SubSubComponent');

    expect(subsubComponent.props().propToTest).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

But I got the following error:

```
Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

Any idea of what is breaking the test?

Comment: Try using `mount` instead of `shallow`. At least the official docs (https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) shows using `props()` with `mount`.

Comment: Thanks @AsenArizanov !